# Correctly using np.where() to output dataframe rather than a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying return the Date (index column using set_index()) where the measurement at one location is twice the measurement at another. I need to show the dates and the speeds at the first location.

Here is what I have so far...

```
c = np.where(data['Loc1']== 2*data['Loc9'])
c
```

which returns a truple... How can I get it to show the dates and wind speeds?

Slowly learning Python here.

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` will return the indices to the rows meeting the criteria, so you then need to use the indices to select the rows of the DataFrame, e.g. using `.loc`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Setup:
data = pd.DataFrame({"Loc1":[4,2,3], "Loc9": [2, 3, 4]})
c = np.where(data['Loc1']== 2*data['Loc9'])
data.loc[c]
```

Comment: I think I tried that previously (or some variation) but got an error. Tried it just now and got an error. KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([15, 1316, 1776, 3145, 4283, 6040], dtype='int64', name='Date')] are in the [index]"

Comment: Hard to trouble shoot without full understanding of the objects and your code - can you post a reproducible small sample of the data and code you have?